# Firebase Cloud Messaging - What is the Dictionary structure?

Tags: javascript, android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

It should be the same for all, but I'm using Javascript. I know this much:

```
const toSend = {
            notification: {
                title: 'Example Title',
                body: 'Example Body',
                icon: '@drawable/launcher_icon'
            }
        };
```

Is there documentation for the whole structure with all available parameters?

I currently need Android's **Channel ID**, **Channel Name**, **Channel Description**, **Color**, **Importance**, **Priority**, etc. I prefer the whole structure though for future use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using `sendToDevice()` referring to example code on Github, looks like that is now legacy. `send()` uses parameters like **andoid** and platform specific parameters.

The documentation is found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_specific_devices

I found the source code:

```
export interface BaseMessage {
    data?: {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
    notification?: Notification;
    android?: AndroidConfig;
    webpush?: WebpushConfig;
    apns?: ApnsConfig;
    fcmOptions?: FcmOptions;
}
```

Which translates to:

**Android**

```
export interface AndroidConfig {
    /**
     * Collapse key for the message. Collapse key serves as an identifier for a
     * group of messages that can be collapsed, so that only the last message gets
     * sent when delivery can be resumed. A maximum of four different collapse keys
     * may be active at any given time.
     */
    collapseKey?: string;
    /**
     * Priority of the message. Must be either `normal` or `high`.
     */
    priority?: ('high' | 'normal');
    /**
     * Time-to-live duration of the message in milliseconds.
     */
    ttl?: number;
    /**
     * Package name of the application where the registration tokens must match
     * in order to receive the message.
     */
    restrictedPackageName?: string;
    /**
     * A collection of data fields to be included in the message. All values must
     * be strings. When provided, overrides any data fields set on the top-level
     * {@link Message}.
     */
    data?: {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
    /**
     * Android notification to be included in the message.
     */
    notification?: AndroidNotification;
    /**
     * Options for features provided by the FCM SDK for Android.
     */
    fcmOptions?: AndroidFcmOptions;
}
```

**Web**

```
export interface WebpushConfig {
    /**
     * A collection of WebPush headers. Header values must be strings.
     *
     * See {@link https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8030#section-5 | WebPush specification}
     * for supported headers.
     */
    headers?: {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
    /**
     * A collection of data fields.
     */
    data?: {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
    /**
     * A WebPush notification payload to be included in the message.
     */
    notification?: WebpushNotification;
    /**
     * Options for features provided by the FCM SDK for Web.
     */
    fcmOptions?: WebpushFcmOptions;
}
```

**iOS**

```
export interface ApnsConfig {
    /**
     * A collection of APNs headers. Header values must be strings.
     */
    headers?: {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
    /**
     * An APNs payload to be included in the message.
     */
    payload?: ApnsPayload;
    /**
     * Options for features provided by the FCM SDK for iOS.
     */
    fcmOptions?: ApnsFcmOptions;
}
```

**Analytics**

```
export interface FcmOptions {
    /**
     * The label associated with the message's analytics data.
     */
    analyticsLabel?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax looks like below (in python)

```
body = json.dumps(data_object)

def send_notification(topic, title, body):
"""Send FCM notification to a specific topic"""
message = messaging.Message(
    topic=topic,
    data={"message": body},
    notification=messaging.Notification(
        title=title,
        body=body
    )
)

# Send a message to the devices subscribed to the provided topic.
response = messaging.send(message)
# Response is a message ID string.
print('Successfully sent message:', response)
```